# React - How to get the scroll position of a div in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a side nav bar having a title and some other info inside of it, title name is sticky, and the side panel is acquiring height of 100vh. I want my title div (`sticky-title`) to have `box-shadow` only when user scrolls down (when the context is greater than 100vh). In other words, box-shadow property initially should not be there, but it should come up when the user scrolls down the page. I tried triggering scroll EventListener but it is taking the main window's scroll position though I want the scroll position of my sidebar div to be considered.

Below is code sandbox playground link to the same.

https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-glitter-6ds36

Comment: Have you looked into [Element.scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop)? All you need is a a [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) to the sidebar.

Comment: @NateLevin Thanks! I am able to use scrollTop and achieved the desired results in the playground. I gave the id to my div and triggered the handler on `onScroll`

However, in my application, this div is generated by a UI library (and there is no id associated with that div). The other problem is - since this div gets by UI library how can I trigger the `onScroll` event on it?

https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-fire-9bksx?file=/src/App.js
This is the working.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized I used the same link when I pointed out refs. [This](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) is the link I meant to point you towards. All you should have to do is something like `<Component ref={this.refName} />`

Comment: I am trying to understand useRef, but it is a bit new to me. Can I be able to access those elements using refs which is being created by DOM that don't appear in render function? Hope what I am asking is making sense. @NateLevin

Comment: Could you provide us with how you are using the component? You could get a ref to the topmost element, and then use `querySelector`s to get to the element you want.

Answer (score 1):

See if this changes can help you in `App.js`:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    
    // Select the title wrapper
    const title = document.querySelector('.sticky-title');
    
    const titleTop = title.offsetTop; // find the top position of title block 
                                      // relative to the window top

    window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {

      console.log("hi", titleTop);
      setScroll(this.scrollY >= titleTop); // when window.scrollY is greater than top 
                                           // the top of the title block the scroll 
                                           // state is set to True  
    });
  }, []);
```

also in the JSX portion of `App.js`:

```
<div className="panel" style={{ height: 2000 }}>{/*2000px to scroll the page easier*/}
  ...
</div>
```

and `style.css`:

```
.panel {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 2px solid black;
  white-space: pre-line;
  /* overflow: auto; */ <---- delete this because it prevents position: sticky to work
}
```

Comment: Line equivalent to this - const title = document.querySelector('.sticky-title'); in my code is returning null.

Comment: Just try to select the parent element of the `<h2>` element. You can give it and `id="title"` and then `const title = document.querySelector('#title');`